# ArrayIndexOutOfBound exception even though I check for array length!

Tags: java, exception, arrays

I have the following code in some app:

```
int lowRange=50;
int[] ageRangeIndividual = {6, 10, 18, 25, 45, 65, 90};
int index=0;
for (; index<ageRangeIndividual.length-1 && ageRangeIndividual[index]<=lowRange;index++);
```

I am getting an "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7"  in the for line! even though I explicitly specify to break the cycle if index < last indexable item in the array!

This does not happen *always*, but after some time of running said program (lowRange varies each time the function is called)

What am I not seeing?

Comment: You actually tell it to stop one item before the end (the `-1` isn't necessary since you're using `<`), but that shouldn't cause this problem

Comment: I don't see any reason for an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in your code snippet. Is the code complete or are you missing anything?

Comment: Show us the code, you're actually using! The current code doesn't throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` with any value of `lowRange`.

Comment: Just as fyi, you can declare and initialize index in your for loops as follows: `for(int index=0;` ...

Comment: @James, the point of the code is apparently to search for the first item in the array greater than `lowRange`. Declaring the index before the loop allows him to see and use the result of the search afterwards :-)

Comment: @Péter Török: Indeed, I figured that out afterwards (see comment below). There's not much you can do with that variable if it's limited to a scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you've posted doesn't throw an exception, on its own. In fact, your array bounds check is one off - you're being too conservative, unless you really don't intend to check the last value. It would normally just be

```
index < ageRangeIndividual.length
```

You say it happens eventually - do you have any other threads changing the value of `index` or `ageRangeIndividual`?

I presume you're about to use `index` in the next line - personally I'd find it clearer if this were wrapped up in a method:

```
// Rename to something more appropriate, perhaps
public static int findIndexOverMinimum(int[] values, int minimum)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
    {
        if (values[i] > minimum)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1; // Or throw an exception, whichever is most appropriate
}
```

I really don't like for loops which have no body, and which use an existing variable for indexing. It's all perfectly valid, but it just feels wrong.

Comment: For the last part, it's useful if you break early in the loop and you want to check the index to see if that happened. That's a big reason I like python's `for/else` construct, it eliminates the need for most of that

Comment: @Michael: I find that requiring the index later is *usually* an indication that refactoring will make it simpler. Not always, but usually. Or I keep a separate "bestIndex" or something like that. The iteration variable itself feels "temporary" somehow...

Comment: This way of using an iterative structure is an adaptation of a basic algorithm often used to find a value in a sequence. If the temp variable contains "nothing" it means that the value wasn't found.

@Michael Mroze: As you probably know, the return statement in Jon's answer acts as a break.

Answer (score 0):

An `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` appears when you're referring to an array index value that exceeds it's length value minus 1 (you're basically fishing for something that isn't there).

In this case, index would need to reach 7 followed by an an access attempt for this to happen (exceeds 0-6). The expression `ageRangeIndividual.length-1` would give 6 (number of elements in an array minus one) and the expression `index<ageRangeIndividual.length-1` should evaluate to false. In turn the second expression after the && operator shouldn't be evaluated and so shouldn't trigger the `Exception` in the first place.

The only thing I can think of is whether the actual code you're testing is different or whether `index<ageRangeIndividual.length-1` is being evaluated as intended. According to operator precedence ( http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html ) the substraction should be processed first.